# Complex SQL postgres query into ActiveRecord notation?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hoping an **ActiveRecord** wizard can help me determine if this kind of query can be done with a AR statement, i.e. without executing the raw SQL or diving into Arel?

I'm getting close but can't seem to figure out how to add the subquery in. I'm on **Rails 5.1.1**.

```
SELECT s.id as stock_id, s.count, adjustments.count as 
adjustment_count, adjustments.reason as adjustment_reason
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE inventory_id = 6) AS s
LEFT JOIN adjustments 
ON (s.id = adjustments.stock_id AND adjustments.reason='run_use')
```

The end result should be all Stock that have inventory id 6 with the extra columns showing what Adjustment was made to them, if they exist.

If I run the RAW SQL in Navicat I get this result, which is what I'm trying to get via ActiveRecord:[image]

This gets me close, but it just produces stock_ids 11 and 10:

```
Stock.where(inventory:6)
.left_joins(:adjustments)
.where("adjustments.reason = 'run_use'")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what you've tried so far and what's not working. Otherwise, we have to be wizards at both ActiveRecord and raw SQL to even try to help you.

Comment: Good point! I edited my answer with the AR statement that gets me close. Any idea on how to include the "subquery" part from the raw SQL, ie. the "(SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE inventory_id = 6) AS available_stock" portion?

Comment: You should also probably state in plain English what it is you're trying to select. It's a little confusing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it's confusing and thanks for trying to help. I revised my question to shorten the query a bit and hopefully it's a little clearer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these should work for you:

```
Stock.eager_load(:adjustments)
  .where("adjustments.reason = ? OR stocks.inventory_id = ?", "run_use", 6)
```

or

```
Stock.eager_load(:adjustments)
  .where(adjustments: { reason: "run_use" }, inventory_id = 6)
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome and I'm amazed it's so simple. I need to read up on eager_load, obviously. The first statement is correct, it pulls the three. The second option only pulls 2, like the other attempts I was making. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's simple because you didn't need that subquery in the first place. Add `.to_sql` to see the raw SQL it's producing.

Comment: Was just reading up on eager_load and see that i's doing the left join part. Any idea how to include the fields from Adjustments in the query results like my screen shot above, i.e. the "adjustments.count as adjustment_count, adjustments.reason as adjustment_reason" ? thanks

Comment: add `.select("stocks.*, adjustments.count AS 
adjustment_count, adjustments.reason AS adjustment_reason")` 

or 

`.pluck("stocks.id, stocks.count, adjustments.count, adjustments.reason")` if you want the raw output

Comment: ok, i see what that does. very cool! Thank you so much for the help, and @jvillian too.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. It seems you're trying to say:

> Give me all Stock that belong to Inventory with id = 6 that also have Adjustments with a reason of 'run use'.

How about something like:

```
Stock.
  where(inventory_id: 6).
  joins(:adjustments).
  where(adjustments: { reason: 'run_use' })
```

from the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: That's better notation than I have in my AR statement, but still doesn't factor in the subquery to select all the stocks that belong to inventory_id 6 in the LEFT table (stocks). What I'm getting is the 2 adjustments but missing the one stock that doesn't have any adjustment. Hope I'm explaining this correctly, been staring at it so much today ... :)  To answe your question...I'm trying to get all stocks that belong to inventory id = 6 PLUS any that have any adjustment as well.